# Maximum row size error - works with lazy SELECT INTO, does not with INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I should stress the below is a curiosity on a lazy bit of manipulation work so please don't waste any time on it - just if you happen to have a suggestion off the top of your head.

Messing around with a convenience piece creating a large flat table for future use in a mail file.

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot create a row of size 11559 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

Now I took the lazy approach originally and used `SELECT * INTO FROM` to create a template table (~500 columns, all varchar(max)) with no issues. If I then truncate the created table and insert into it (stressing from the SAME source table), I return the error above.

(For clarity, I'm also created the table "manually" (i.e. `CREATE TABLE`) and get the same issue with inserting into)

While I'm familiar with the row size limit (hence the use of `varchar(max)`), what's especially strange is that on the source table, showcontig returns a MaximumRecordSize is 3676 on the source table, so I'm unable to determine where the problem lies.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Comment: Can you please explain with some examples and test data for us to repro the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server has the limit of 8K per table row](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx).
You should review and resize all nvarchar(nnn) columns and/or split (and normalize, I suspect) the table into several ones. 
Another workaround is to use nvarchar(max) but be careful.